# Vagrant: do not map hostname to loopback address in /etc/hosts

Tags: vagrant, fedora, hosts, vagrantfile, resolve

I am using Vagrant (**v1.7.2**) to provision Linux (Fedora 22) hosts, and the [vagrant-hostmanager](https://github.com/smdahlen/vagrant-hostmanager) plugin (**v1.6.1**)
to write `/etc/hosts` so that hosts can access each other.

My `Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "workshop"

  config.hostmanager.enabled = true
  config.hostmanager.include_offline = true

  config.vm.define "server" do |server|
    server.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
    server.vm.hostname = "server.local"
  end

  config.vm.define "client" do |client|
    client.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.20"
    client.vm.hostname = "client.local"
  end

end
```

When I `vagrant up`, the `server` VM has the following `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 server.ipademo.local server
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

## vagrant-hostmanager-start
192.168.33.10   server.ipademo.local

192.168.33.20   client.ipademo.local

## vagrant-hostmanager-end
```

(For VM `client`, substitute `s/server/client/` on the *first line only*.)

Because Vagrant >= 1.5.0 runs the vagrant-hostmanager plugin before provisioning, I also tried running hostmanager *during* provisions by changing the `Vagrantfile` to:

```
  config.hostmanager.enabled = false
  config.hostmanager.include_offline = true
  config.vm.provision :hostmanager
```

This had the same outcome.

### Problem description

The `127.0.0.1 <fqdn> <shortname>` line conflicts with the information added by vagrant-hostmanager.  I need to suppress the association of the hostname to the loopback address, so that on every VM the hostname resolves to the private network address, as added by *vagrant-hostmanager*.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I think even without the vagrant-hostmanager plugin you would have the same. as soon as you set a hostname for your VM /etc/hosts will add the hostname in the 127.0.0.1 loopback so I would assume this part is not managed by the plugin and is left untouched

Comment: @FrédéricHenri that's correct.  The problem is that the changes made by Vagrant to `/etc/hosts` are interfering with successful use of *vagrant-hostmanager*.  I got around it with some provision scripts (see answer).

Comment: Good so with scripting its possible - did you try to hook in the plugin ? potentially it could be an improvement to be made there so useful for others ..

Comment: @FrédéricHenri there we no conditionals in the plugin but I agree it could be useful; I will file a ticket as a start.

Answer (score 2):

The cause of the problem is Vagrant's *change host name* capability for Fedora guests.  In particular, in `plugins/guests/fedora/cap/change_host_name.rb`:

```
def update_etc_hosts                             
  ip_address = '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}'
  search     = "^(#{ip_address})\\s+#{Regexp.escape(current_hostname)}(\\s.*)?$"
  replace    = "\\1 #{fqdn} #{short_hostname}"
  expression = ['s', search, replace, 'g'].join('@')

  sudo("sed -ri '#{expression}' /etc/hosts")
end
```

The `update_etc_hosts` method replaces the original hostname (for Fedora, this is `localhost.localdomain`, bound to the loopback address `127.0.0.1`) with the new hostname.  It then updates `/etc/hostname` with the **short hostname**, although system calls still return the full hostname because it appears in `/etc/hosts`.

### The solution

I provided additional provisioners (which run *after* the above described hackery takes place) to:

1. Query the **long hostname** (FQDN) and write it back to `/etc/hostname`.  This is needed so `hostname --fqdn` actually returns the full hostname after we repair `/etc/hosts` in the next step.
2. Restore the loopback line in `/etc/hosts` so that the machine's hostname resolves to the private network address as set by *vagrant-hostmanager*.

The order is critical.  Here's the `Vagrantfile` code:

```
# Vagrant's "change host name" sets the short host name.
# Before we undo the /etc/hosts silliness (see below) let's
# reset /etc/hostname to the *full* host name
#
config.vm.provision "shell",
  inline: "hostname --fqdn > /etc/hostname && hostname -F /etc/hostname"

# Vagrant's "change host name" capability for Fedora
# maps hostname to loopback, conflicting with hostmanager.
# We must repair /etc/hosts
#
config.vm.provision "shell",
  inline: "sed -ri 's/127\.0\.0\.1\s.*/127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain/' /etc/hosts"
```

Answer (score 1):

Most linux distributions have the [same issue](https://github.com/devopsgroup-io/vagrant-hostmanager/issues/203) caused by the change_host_name vagrant capability ([redhat](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/plugins/guests/redhat/cap/change_host_name.rb#L30), [debian](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/plugins/guests/debian/cap/change_host_name.rb#L24), [arch](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/plugins/guests/arch/cap/change_host_name.rb#L18), etc) when the hostname is set via Vagrant.

The following line from `change_host_name` prepends the vm hostname and vm name as aliases to `127.0.0.1` when the hostname is set, which conflicts with vagrant-hostmanager's aliasing.

```
sed -i'' '1i 127.0.0.1\\t#{name}\\t#{basename}' /etc/hosts
```

[Vagrant authors have said that this is intentional](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7263#issuecomment-224109329) and that they aren't planning to fix it, because it works as-is, as long as you don't modify /etc/hosts (which vagrant-hostmanager does).

Interestingly, many tools (dig, host, nslookup) use the LAST specified alias, which works fine with the defualt Vagrant behavior. Unfortunately, other tools, namely ones using [gethostbyname](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gethostbyname.3.html) or [/etc/nsswitch.conf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html), have different behavior.

Ping, for example, seems to use the first alias in /etc/hosts, while Curl (when compiled to use NSS) uses multiple aliases as fallback from top down.

Because of this, having an alias match multiple IPs is generally discouraged.

The following `Vagrantfile` workaround should be sufficient:

```
config.hostmanager.enabled = true

name = "name"
hostname = "hostname"

config.vm.define name do |machine|
  machine.vm.hostname = hostname
  machine.vm.provision :shell, inline: "sed -i'' '/^127.0.0.1\\t#{hostname}\\t#{name}$/d' /etc/hosts"
  ...
end
```